# How to add custom color in Xcode storyboard color picker?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am planning to make theme color of UI elements in application.
how we show custom color(Golden Color) like Black color in picker menu

[image]

is it possible? like we can add custom Property as shown in snapsho[image]t

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a new palette by clicking "New" here:
[image]

A new palette "Unnamed" will be created. You can rename that palette by clicking the cog again and choosing "Rename..." Then, you'll need to click on the objects you want to capture the color of, and drag the color of those objects into the color chip area:

[image]

Once you've captured the color, you can even rename it something that indicates where it's normally used, providing more information to the recipient than just the color.

[source](https://discussions.apple.com/message/27227340#27227340)

Comment: Although this is a good link and and answers the question, you really should add the steps to the answer as link only answers are not usually welcome on SO.

Comment: Edited with step by step instructions found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/27227340#27227340)

Comment: Much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can add custom color as folow

1. Select color property(Background color, text color, etc.). A popup is shown from that select "other" option.

[image]

2. A color picker will be opened. Here you can set your custom color by RGB/Hex Code and you can set opacity.

[image]

The color will be applied and visible under "Recently Used Colors". This is how you can add custom colors but as far as I know you can't add colors in that default list.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i know these simple things. my question is how we show custom color like goldenColor in picker menu.

Comment: ok, but it is not possible to modify the Apple's default color list.

Answer (score 5):

As of Xcode 9 you can add colors to your asset catalog.
Open your asset catalog, click the + and add a color set.
Click on the color that was created and you can name it and set the color using the inspector.
Thereafter that color shows up in storyboard color chooses in the area called Named Colors.

Comment: This is a great answer

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this follow these steps

***) In the Project navigator, select the asset catalog, click the Add button (+) at the bottom. In the pop-up menu, choose the type of asset set to create**

[image]

[image]

***) then you'll see the color asset on storyboard.**

[image]

**Cheers :)**